# Arial font zebra printer not printing the zero character

Tags: ascii, zebra-printers, zpl

Zebra printer won't print the zero character for Arial and Arial bold fonts. Instead it shows a whitespace.

The thing why is this happening is due to the fact that I installed only certain font sizes and characters 0-9 and A-Z. When I try to print the character zero with all the characters installed, the zero character shows. Therefore, what ASCII code is there for the digit ZERO on a Zebra Printer?

**Without further mentioning, what is the ASCII code for 0 on a Zebra printer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are getting tripped up by the font encoding in the printer.  ZPL has been around for a really long time, long before unicode and standardized code pages.  As such, it has some anachronisms which are its defaults.

If you are using UTF-8 strings (or just simple ASCII), try switching to the UTF-8 character set using `^CI28`.  Put it near the top of the format and before any text fields.